# Javascript Directory 2 Level Down

Tags: javascript, directory

I am using this code to check if a file exists, that takes a string for argument:

```
function UrlExists(url){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}
```

Then in my directory:

```
main_folder
     script_folder
           script.js
     page_folder
           page.php
     index.php
```

I have my code in `script.js`
Test case: `alert(UrlExists('../index.php'));` returns `true`
Test case: `alert(UrlExists('../page_folder/page.php'));` returns `false`

How should I go 2 level down?